# Can Kdevelop 5.0 still load existing external cmake project

Tags: cmake, kdevelop

I know that KDevelop 4 was able to [import CMake projects](https://rtt-lwr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutos/kdev-tuto.html) (hand written CMakeLists.txt not generated by KDevelop) ... but now after I installed ubuntu 18.04 it seems this is not possible anymore (the `Project > Open/Import Project` dialog simply refuse take `CMakeLists.txt` when I click on it )? Or I miss something?

I tried to run `cmake .. -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`
[as described here](http://kfunk.org/2016/08/23/whats-new-in-kdevelop-5-0/) but it refuse with error message:

```
prokop@s2-041:~/git/SimpleSimulationEngine/cpp/Build$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS
Parse error in command line argument: -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS
Should be: VAR:type=value
CMake Error: No cmake script provided.
CMake Error: Problem processing arguments. Aborting.
```

**EDIT**

OK, so according to the advice below I run

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
```

and now it generate `compile_commands.json` but I still cannot open it with KDevelope ... the Import Project dialog still shows everything gray and inactive (see screenshots below). Not sure if it matters that I run KDevelop under `xubuntu 18.04 LTS` (not Kubuntu) and `Gnome-Flashback Desktop environment`.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should still work in KDevelop 5. There's no need to run `cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ..`, KDevelop will do it for you.

The version of KDevelop packaged in Ubuntu 18.04 is rather old and has many known bugs, please try the [5.4.2 AppImage](https://www.kdevelop.org/download) and see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: OK, it works now. Maybe it worked also with default ubuntu KDevelop, but I tried to open file `CMakeList.txt` or `*.json` which does not work. In this ne version the dialog stated explicitly "Open Directory" which helped me.

Comment: But still, I have a some inconvenience with KDevelop. I have project with multiple targets (hundrets, they are small 3D demos) and when I try to choose which one to run I always have to go to `Run > Configure Lunches` ... delete the previous one, and add the new one, apply, then build and run. That is too much work. In `Code::Blocks` which I used up to now I can just select build target from drop-down list by one click, and hit run. Is there some simple option like this in KDevelop?

Comment: In `Configure Launches` you can create more than one launch option. Then switch between them with the `Run > Current Launch Configuration` menu.

Comment: I tried this `Build Sequence` box in lower left corner, and also right-click to build target in `projects` menu/treeview but it does not work. `Run > Configure Launches` and setting Build Dependencies works, but it is quite tedious.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the path to your source (top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file) at the **end** of your command, after any options.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON ..
```

Here is the command line syntax [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#synopsis).

---

**Edit**: As Tsyvarev points out, CMake specifically complains about your `-D` syntax, which is missing the assignment to `ON`.

Comment: Actually, CMake complains about missing **assignment** in the option setting. Since `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` has a flag semantic, for set this flag on should pass `-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON` (or, with type set, `-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=ON`). As for order between source directory and other options, it is actually not so important, despite what is stated in the docs.